# Combining PDFs in Folder using ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pdf

This was able to combine two pdfs in a folder into one pdf, but unable to combine more than this.

```
import arcpy, os

# Set the workspace.
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Output"

#Set file name and remove if it already exists
pdfPath = r"C:\Output\Map.pdf"
if os.path.exists(pdfPath):
    os.remove(pdfPath)

# List all of the pdf files in the output folder.
# pdfList is a Python List returned from the ListFiles function.
pdfList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.pdf")

#Create the file and append pages
pdfDoc = arcpy.mp.PDFDocumentCreate(pdfPath)

for f in pdfList:
    pdfDoc.appendPages(f)   

pdfDoc.saveAndClose()

del pdfDoc
```

[image: Error I received]

Comment: What's the error? appendPages for a PDF should do any number of PDFs into a single document. There isn't a limit of 2.

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pdfDoc.appendPages` doesn't know which folder to look in for the indicated PDF.

Try this:

```
import os
for f in pdfList:
    pdfDoc.appendPages(os.path.join (r"C:\Output", f))
```